# Adding a value to a single key but added to multiple keys

Tags: python

In the code below, very strangely to me, 0 and 1 are added to the BOTH keys:

```
zip_to_dict1 = zip(["a", "b"], [[]]*2)
dict1 = dict(zip_to_dict1)
dict1["a"].append(0)
dict1["b"].append(1)
print(dict1["a"], dict1["b"])
# [0, 1] [0, 1]
```

However, this works somehow:

```
zip_to_dict2 = zip(["a", "b"], [[], []])
dict2 = dict(zip_to_dict2)
dict2["a"].append(0)
dict2["b"].append(1)
print(dict2["a"], dict2["b"])
# [0] [1]
```

Is there any difference between `[[]]*2` and `[[], []]`?:

```
[[]]*2 == [[], []]
# True
```

...What's the problem?

(Note: I'm using Python 3.4.1)

Comment: How can I close the question?

Comment: Don't worry about it. Nobody can answer the question, and even though your question is marked as a duplicate it may be helpful to people with a similar question doing a search.